# How can I share a single config file across multiple locations in multiple environments?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, web-config, app-config

We have 5 different dev teams, each with their own dev environment (server, build, database)  Each dev environment replicates our test/preprod/prod environment.  There are many projects (>100 including all web apps, web services, windows services, etc).

We maintain a single config file just for connection strings in each environment.  All of our web.config and exe.config files reference this file via configsrc.  This is simple for test/pre-prod/prod because devs don't have access to these.  But for the dev environments they do.  All the dev environment connection strings are identical except that they point to different servers.

I want to move to a variable library and use token replacement during build/release so that I can merge all of this in to one singular file that doesn't have to be maintained per environment.

The one problem I can't solve for is how to handle local builds on developer machines that point to the dev databases.  Transforms and tokenization works great on TFS during a release, not so much on local builds.  Slow Cheetah wants a publish and Fast Koala doesn't work with later .Net frameworks.  Getting devs to update another teams connection strings when they add a new one is nigh impossible.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. Combine the two approaches. The baseline config file is local. Then there is a build configuration ("Release", "Deploy", whatever) that transforms the configuration file into a tokenized version. Then the deployment process can do standard token replacement with the correct values for the environment being deployed.
2. Use WebDeploy packages with parameters.xml/setparameters.xml, which allows you to specify deployment-time configuration transforms.

Comment: I guess I missed an inmportant point... our localhost environments point to the same dev db as the dev server for that team. So if one dev team creates a new connection string, I need it to go in to a source controlled file so that when they merge up, other teams will get the string when they merge down to their team branch. But if it comes down with another teams db named in the connection string, then we end up with teams always clobbering each others configs.